# Reset or Update Row Position Integer in Database Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-cursor

I am working on a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 for resetting an integer column in a database table.  This integer column stores or persists the display order of the item rows.  Users are able to drag and drop items in a particular sort order and we persist that order in the database table using this *"Order Rank Integer"*.

Display queries for items always append a *"ORDER BY OrderRankInt"* when retrieving data so the user sees the items in the order they previously specified.

The problem is that this integer column collects a lot of duplicate values after the table items are re-ordered a bit.  Hence...

```
Table
--------
Name | OrderRankInt
a    | 1
b    | 2
c    | 3
d    | 4
e    | 5
f    | 6
```

After a lot of reordering by the user becomes....

```
Table
--------
Name | OrderRankInt
a    | 1
b    | 2
c    | 2
d    | 2
e    | 2
f    | 6
```

These duplicates are primarily because of insertions and user specified order numbers.  We're not trying to prevent duplicate order ranks, but we'd like a way to 'Fix' the table on item inserts/modifies.

Is there a way I can reset the *OrderRankInt* column with a single UPDATE Query?
Or do I need to use a cursor?  What would the syntax for that cursor look like?

Thanks,
Kervin

**EDIT**

Update with **Remus Rusanu** solution. Thanks!!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EPC_FixTableOrder
@sectionId int = 0
AS
BEGIN

-- "Common Table Expression" to append a 'Row Number' to the table
WITH tempTable AS 
(
    SELECT OrderRankInt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderRankInt) AS rn
    FROM dbo.[Table]
    WHERE sectionId = @sectionId -- Fix for a specified section
)
UPDATE tempTable        
SET OrderRankInt = rn;  -- Set the Order number to the row number via CTE

END
GO
```

Comment: I am not sure that I follow how the user reordering updates the OrderId.  Can you provide any more information?

Comment: Probably can be done, yes - but you'll need to add some additional information if you'd like a sample...like what defines the order (in the example, no way to tell why b,c,d,e all have the same order)

Comment: Thanks, I have added some more information.  Basically the user can directly specify the order if they choose to, and the reorder algorithm is simple so it can result in duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with cte as (
 select OrderId, row_number() over (order by Name) as rn
 from Table)
update cte
 set OrderId = rn;
```

This doesn't account for any foreign key relationships, I hope you are taken care of those.

Comment: You might want to order over the OrderRankInt, Name if you want to keep the currently saved ordering but just get rid of the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Fake it. Make the column nullable, set the values to NULL, alter it to be an autonumber, and then turn off autonumber and nullable.

(You could skip the nullable steps.)